# php multiple file upload foreach issue

Tags: php, upload

I am trying to save files from a file upload which has more than one file. But the move_uploaded_file is only executing once. I tried printing $file['tmp_name'] using a foreach loop , but it's printing two array values in one single line as text. How can i fix this .. Thanks ..

```
  public function uploadFile($filename)
    {

        $file_ary = $this->reArrayFiles($_FILES[$filename]);

        foreach ($file_ary as $file) {

           move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'] , '../uploads/' . '.txt');

        }




    }


   function reArrayFiles(&$file_post) {
        $file_ary = array();
        if(!is_array($file_post['name']))
            return array($file_post);
        $file_count = count($file_post['name']);
        $file_keys = array_keys($file_post);
        for ($i=0; $i<$file_count; $i++) {
            foreach ($file_keys as $key) {
                $file_ary[$i][$key] = $file_post[$key][$i];
            }
        }
        return $file_ary;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: You are not showing all of the code, what does something like var_dump($file_ary); give?

Comment: Just do a `print_r($_FILES)` and you will see the structure of the array and then processing it will become obvious

Comment: Is this any different than the question asked 7 minutes earlier?